# Reference error for simple js function call

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting reference error for a simple JavaScript function call. Help me to solve this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="javascript">
        function showPopupForIssueReport()
        {
            alert("The first");
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(null)" onclick="javascript:showPopupForIssueReport()">POPUP</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you paste the error you received. Try to stick with http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<script>` tag has a "type" value that's incorrect for JavaScript. The browser is ignoring it.

Just leave off the "type" attribute completely.

```
<script>
    function showPopupForIssueReport()
    {
        alert("The first");
    }
</script>
```

If you feel you *must* have a "type" (you really don't need it though), use `"text/javascript"`.